# Typoscript - Simplifying passing parameters to an object

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have the following object in Typoscript, that I want to reuse several times:

```
module.headedmenu = COA
module.headedmenu{
    10 = HMENU
    10{
        wrap = <nav><ul><li>|</li></ul></nav>

        special = list
        special.value = ###ROOTID###

        1 = TMENU
        1.NO.doNotLinkIt = 1
    }

    20 = HMENU
    20{

        wrap = <nav><ul>|</ul></nav>
        special = directory
        special.value = ###ROOTID###

        1 = TMENU
        1{
            #Do we really need this??
            expAll= 1

            NO = 1
            NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first-level">|</li>

            ACT = 1
            ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="first-level active">|</li>
        }
    }
}
```

This can be reused like this:

```
10 < module.headedmenu
10.10.special.value = 3
10.20.special.value = 3

20 < module.headedmenu
20.10.special.value = 12
20.20.special.value = 12
```

Is there a way to refactor this, so that I do not need to input more than once the root id? Constants dont cut it, because I want to use it several times. I do not want to have a huge constant list. I want to use it, more like a function that can be passed paramenters.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [registers](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/LoadRegister/Index.html):

```
# Query register where the root id is needed:
module.headedmenu {
    [...]
    special.value = {register:rootId}
    special.value.insertData = 1
    [...]
}

# Set register before rendering element, and
# restore it afterwards:
10 = COA
10 {
    10 = LOAD_REGISTER
    10 {
        rootId = 3
    }

    20 < module.headedmenu

    30 = RESTORE_REGISTER
}
```

Comment: I guess that makes the job done, even though it doesn't seem much more elegant than the original solution... You get upvoted, but I will wait for a better solution.

Comment: It is more elegant in two ways: First and most importantly, you don't need to know the internal workings of `module.headedmenu` in places where you just call it, and second: You need to set the value of the root id only once for each "call". It is just not as short as simple function call would be.